# Extending the SilverStripe File class for Video

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to extend the `File`/`Image` class to recognize `.mp4` files as `Video` class rather than as `File` class.

My code is:

**VideoExtension.php**

```
class VideoExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $db = array(
        'IsAnimation' => 'Boolean',
        'AssociatedStaticPage' => 'Text',
        'BarCode' => 'Text'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('BarCode', 'Bar Code'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('AssociatedStaticPage', 'URL'));
    }
}
```

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
Name: mysite
After:
  - 'framework/*'
  - 'cms/*'
---
# YAML configuration for SilverStripe
# See http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/configuration
# Caution: Indentation through two spaces, not tabs
SSViewer:
  theme: 'simple'

File:
  extensions:
    - VideoExtension
```

With this I get an error. If I change File to Image in the `config.yml` it works. I want this so I can add custom fields in the Admin section.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please include the relevant parts of your code in the question? And: what error do you get?

Comment: Thank you to @3dgoo for cleaning up my post, as you can see I have no idea what I'm doing when posting.

Comment: Happy to help. We all start from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to create a class that extends `File` instead of creating a `DataExtension`. Something like the following:

```
class Video extends File {

    private static $allowed_extensions = array(
        'mpeg', 'mpg', 'mp4', 'm1v', 'mp2', 'mpa', 'mpe', 'ifo', 
        'vob','avi', 'wmv', 'asf', 'm2v', 'qt', 'ogv', 'webm'
    );

    private static $db = array(
        'IsAnimation' => 'Boolean',
        'AssociatedStaticPage' => 'Text',
        'BarCode' => 'Text'
    );


    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('BarCode', 'Bar Code'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('AssociatedStaticPage', 'URL'));

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

We then need to set this class to be used for these file extensions by setting the `File` `class_for_file_extension`. We can do this is in our `mysite/_config/config.yml` file:

```
File:
  class_for_file_extension:
    'mpeg': 'Video'
    'mpg': 'Video'
    'mp4': 'Video'
    'm1v': 'Video'
    'mp2': 'Video'
    'mpa': 'Video'
    'mpe': 'Video'
    'ifo': 'Video'
    'vob': 'Video'
    'avi': 'Video'
    'wmv': 'Video'
    'asf': 'Video'
    'm2v': 'Video'
    'qt': 'Video'
    'ogv': 'Video'
    'webm': 'Video'
```

Comment: Just extending File isn't going to cut it… you'd have to correctly assign the `Video` class to uploads via asset-admin as well.

Comment: Thanks @bummzack you're right. I have added the `class_for_file_extension` that needs to be set to assign the `Video` class to the correct file extensions. Thanks for picking that up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer